# CloudMap usage when VPC is in a centralized account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, service-discovery, aws-cloudmap

To give a high level understanding of the current environment that I am working with. We currently have a networking account that creates everything networking related which then gets shared amongst the other accounts via RAM (dev, staging, production, etc). The other accounts don't have their own VPCs (not even the default ones) just what is shared by the Networking account. Which brings me to my question.

How can my ECS cluster utilize Service Discovery/Cloud Map if the Development account (for example) does not own the VPC? Let me know if there is something more I can answer to help.

I tried setting up cloud map in the networking account, but it doesn't seem that you can share those resources in RAM or does my Development account have access to utilized it.